# Is it possible to successfully exploit a vulnerability on a router remotely if

Tags: authentication

...its remote administration feature is locked down to a single IP/Range? If so, why?

This has been an ongoing office debate for a while now, I claim that it would be possible as it is likely to be the internal web server and the technologies it uses (cgi etc.) that will handle that remote authentication, but I have many people saying that it wouldn't be possible to execute a remote shell because it's locked down by IP. Who is right?

Comment: Never assume it's perfectly safe.  I recently discovered my Motorola Router has a backdoor, which Motorola didn't bother to mention in the User Guide.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "it depends".

"is locked down to a single IP/Range" -- the first question is how is that enforced.  Assuming the whitelist is enforced by the device itself, there's code on your device that takes data off of the wire and decodes them into packets.  Code almost always comes with the potential for vulnerabilities.

If the layer that examines the packets and does the enforcement is what's vulnerable then the router is vulnerable.  If the IP-block layer is sound and it fronts the vulnerable component then you're okay.

It's also possible that the vulnerability is in a component that's not part of the remote admin stuff and not protected by the IP whitelist.

There's also a chance that someone could bounce an attack off of one of your internal hosts via XSS or a compromised host and circumvent your protection by coming from a host on the whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

If a router is "fully vulnerable" that means that its susceptible to having commands or actions taken upon in ways that were not anticipated. Presumably, these actions could be used to circumvent any ACL or access control utilized by the router. There are certainly ways to circumvent access controls, and if a payload is run on the target router then the possibility exists that the access control mechanisms would be disabled anyways.

In theory I would say that this is certainly possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'd be inclined to agree; in terms of the exploit itself, the main debate we are having is regarding the 'heirarchy' of the attack. The debate being 'how can remote code be executed in the first place if the router is locked down by IP?'. I'm personally quite sure that it's actually only the remote login script that will be discriminating against IPs instead of some kind of deeper process within the router software. Even then, the question I personally can't answer is how this software can be exploited if no connection is made in the first place.

Comment: I would agree, but who's to say that there aren't back doors in the router you don't even know about? Say for manufacturer troubleshooting? See : http://thenubbyadmin.com/2014/04/28/a-tale-of-centurylink-backdoors-pci-compliance-and-pain-lots-of-pain/

Answer (score 0):

Some exploits will use javascript from a browser (by visiting a malicious site) to show your router configuration since some vendors store keys to reset passwords in plain text inside configuration files that can be seen by mistake using a cross site scripting attack.  Some hack will even go as far as attempting to log in to 192.168.1.1 with the default password and turn on remote admin for all IPs...

Check this link to see if your router is vunerable:
http://www.routerpwn.com/detect.html

Note that this is only true if web traffic goes out from this router...

Comment: I think you've missed the essence of the question. Exploiting a machine from within the network (which is what you're referring to) is not what OP is asking about. They're asking about remote administration access, ie directly accessing the router via an INPUT rule and not a FORWARD rule to a compromised workstation

Comment: @DKNUCKLES, true, but the attacker could always make it look like it's coming from an internal computer.